# select records from database based on age by the difference of birthday in the column and current days

Tags: mysql

i am working for a report that will show employees name who's age is 59 year by the difference of his birthdate in the records and current date . i tried something but i know it is deprecated but i am showing this for you to understand what i tried . please can  anyone solved this for me  !
 here is my fiddle ...........

```
    "select
    emp.EMP_ID,
    emp.BIRTH_DATE 
    from  bf_hrm_ls_employee as emp 
                            where (DATEDIFF('y',date('Y:m:d'),emp.BIRTH_DATE) = 59) order by emp.EMP_ID"
```

Comment: oh i forgot to add emp.EMP_NAME  but i can solve it with a join query  if that is solved !

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) being deprecated. It *does* say the function only takes two arguments. I think you want the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function instead.

Comment: Sorry about the mistakes @DarwinvonCorax ! and thank u for the hints ! i have managed to get my result !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
SELECT emp.EMP_ID, emp.BIRTH_DATE 
  FROM  bf_hrm_ls_employee AS emp 
  WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, emp.BIRTH_DATE, CURRENT_DATE()) = 59)
  ORDER BY emp.EMP_ID
```

Note the order of the DATE arguments to `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`; the earlier date must be first to give a positive result, which is the reverse of `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: thank u for your effort ! i also did so with the TIMESTAMPDIFF() . Though  @Darwin von Corax  give hints first but  your answer is the  complete answer ! i dont know why my vote or point does'nt count but you owe me +1  for your effort .

Comment: My pleasure to help. (You need to vote on the answer for it to count toward reputation scores. Also, if you *accept* the answer - click the check mark below the vote counter - we *both* get points.)

Comment: oh ho ! sorry sory ! i did it now and just saw the magic! thank u !